# Centered text next to img gets broken by <br />

Tags: html, css

thats the usual "lets vertical center something next to img" but I need two lines. Its good with one line, but looks like the `<br />` spoils  that.

```
<img style="vertical-align: middle;">Centered text
```

results:

```
IMG
IMG   text here
IMG
```

but if I want to do this:

```
<img style="vertical-align: middle;">Centered text<br />new line

IMG
IMG   centered text
IMG
new line
```

how to fix this?

Comment: Do you want the 2 lines to be vertically centered at the side of the image or the second line to go below the image?

Comment: yes, exactly. As soon as I use line break, it screws up

Comment: two inline-block elements with `vertical-align: middle` is probably the cleanest and the most compatible solution, oh seems like Nathan and Adassko already answered that. `=]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your text into `div` with `display: inline-block` or use `float: left` for the image.

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/k4hkS/1/

Comment: thats right, it works. But if I set a width/height to the img, it doesnt get centered

Comment: well, it does for me. Can you edit my fiddle to show what's happening?

Comment: sorry, I was wrong. But try to put a smaller image, it wont be precisely centered

Comment: It is centering. http://jsfiddle.net/vbJwb/3/ The issue with the screenshot is that the height is collapsing to a level which is less than the one you can see on the right side of the image. Therefore, it is not visualized, but it is centre. Also, if you reduce your font-size, you can see the centralization. http://jsfiddle.net/vbJwb/4/ I hope its clear. - @JohnSmith

Comment: @JohnSmith: add `vertical-align: middle` to both `div` and `img`

Comment: Adassko AAAHHHHHH perfect like Cell :-) http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2013/186/a/3/perfect_cell___dbz_androids__amp__cell_saga_by_anjoicaros-d6312af.png

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vbJwb/1/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png" style="vertical-align: middle;"><div>Centered text<br />new line</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
div{display: inline-block;}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't run when you hear the word "table", you can easily do this with a table, and customize it from your css file.

You can use the inline styles for the cell: `align="left" valign="center"`

Demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/bsj4t/

Comment: no, im not scared by tables - but do scared with those invalid align="left" valign="center" :-)

Comment: Yes that's why you should customize them in your css file, use equivalent css styles instead of deprecated inline styles(if you plan to use them in an email template, you will be forced to use old syntax and no html5 doctype)