# Text centered next to image

Tags: html, image, text, alignment

I made a JSFiddle of my current site:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/87bhL/)

```
#text{
font-size:25px;
margin-left:4px;
    margin-top:25px;
}
```

is the most important I think.
But I want the text to be vertically centered next to the image. 
But the `margin-top:25px;` doesn't really work. Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967022/how-do-i-vertical-center-text-next-to-an-image-in-html-css

Comment: You can use the search before reposting same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419806/centered-text-next-to-img-gets-broken-by-br/20420874#20420874    And your fiddle in case you still can't make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/87bhL/14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

should do the trick: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87bhL/11/). `margin` does not have an effect on inline elements like your a#lehrer.